# extensionless url opening in Apache results in not found when file exists

Tags: php, json, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have the following setup:
Wamp server with Apache 2.4.27, PHP 7.1.8

Then I am using our own CMS to develop a website.

It is installed in the www folder under `PeerCMS$/test/` ($ to hide it in wamp overview)

Now I am browsing to `http://localhost/PeerCMS$/test/`structure
This is working fine. It displays our CMS stucture page to generate a database. When we save this, it will be saved to stucture.json in the same `test` folder.

After this, `http://localhost/PeerCMS$/test/structure` isn't reachable anymore. 404 Not Found.

If we remove the .json file, it is reachable again.

This is our .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteBase /PeerCMS$/test/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
```

I think that one is ok.
Does anyone know where to look for this?

Comment: Not a problem with htaccess then I think - see here for details on how the rules a re processed http://htaccess.mwl.be?share=35235336-ee37-5b73-b9eb-41fc9d170221

Comment: Yeay, I allready know that site. Indeed I guess it is something with apache and handling the URLs